# Setting a Type for Svelte Component Properties

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to set a type on my svelte components properties:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Stage } from './types';

    export let stages: Stage[] = [];
</script>


<div>
    {stages}
</div>
```

`types.ts` looks like this:

```
export interface Stage {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    value: number;
    deals: number;
}
```

When I run the app I get a 500 with the error message:

`SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: Stage`

Can svelte component properties be types?

Comment: yes they can, try `import type { Stage } from './types';` and see if that works, otherwise no idea

Comment: @StephaneVanraes - you're right! Adding the `type` after the `import` worked! If you make that an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is somehow finding a conflict between two definitions of "Stage", is this component maybe also called Stage ?

Regardless, this helps:

```
import type { Stage } from './types';
```